# I need my character to be honest

Tags: creative-writing, fiction, characters

What I am writing is a love story. The problem is: I am trying to make my female character tell the truth to her love interest--the truth about herself. 
What’s stopping her from telling him is that when she told the truth to her ex, he ended up killed. So she is afraid the love interest will see the same end.

How can I make her tell him? Any advice on forbidden love?

Answer (score 1):

Possible solutions:

1. Honesty/transparency is her top core value
2. Something makes him suspicious, so he asks her a pointed question. Her only other option would be to blatantly lie, so she tells him then.
3. She doesn't tell him, but some circumstance gives it away.